# What is the difference between .sln formats for 2010, 2012 and 2013 visual studios

Tags: visual-studio

What's the difference between visual studio solution formats for different vertions? What is added? It is possible to open vs 2010 sln files with VS 2013 but is there any benifits if upgrade vs 2010 sln files to fv 2013 sln files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I know of, just the version number.  The project files are the ones that change the most.  It was always possible to open an old solution, Visual Studio automatically converted the solution and project files, that rarely goes wrong.

New for VS2012 and up, it can open and save VS2010 solutions and projects without (typically) having to convert them.  A very popular feature request from customers, greatly simplifying the transition to an updated VS version.  Painful in the olden days when not every team member or partner updates at the same time.

So no, no benefit that I can think of.